# Anime in the early 1990-2000s sci-fi with a trap scene at the beginning?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I only watched the first episode years ago and it was like a gundam/sci-fi style. There was a upper class dance going on I believe? and this girl sneaks down the hall to this computer(crystal?) only to get the item and drop her chest to the floor- its a guy, he was playing a girl to sneak in.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say "years ago;" what year would that have been?  Where did you see it?  What language was it in?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to this site. I'm really not sure about the year...maybe 2000+? It was in Japanese I believe. I saw it at an old anime store growing up called "Otaku House" They would do little movies or shows at night- the owners wanted to share the anime for the trap scene alone. I think the main character had blue or purple hair..?